# Express and Mongoose: Not getting a response from callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, callback

I have been stuck on this issue for a few days now and I have finally pinpointed the issue to this problem:

In the following code, I am trying to create a simple user registration/authentication system in my React app. I am using fetch to send the user data to my express server which then uses mongoose to update the mongo document. Upon a successful update, I am trying to return a simple success message via an express response.

I am able to successfully reach the express server and update the Mongo Database but I am not able to get a response back in the browser saying everything went ok. I do not send a response or touch the `res` object in any way prior to sending. I do not get any sort of error message either. I am looking for any sort of help on how I could send a response upon a sucessfull callback.

UPDATE: I tried creating a new project from scratch that is just a simple registration page connected to an express server with the same code as below. I get a 400 response and message back in the browser if i type invalid fields but if I register succesfully I still cannot get a 200 response and message back in the browser.

Front-end:

```
 handlesubmit() {
    var data = this.state;
   fetch( 'http://localhost:8000/register', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then((response) => {
       response.text().then((data) => {
           console.log(data);
       });
   })
}
```

Mongoose Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const saltRounds = 10;

var userschema = new Schema (
    {
        email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        username: {type: String, required: true},
        password: {type: String, required: true },
    }
);

userschema.pre('save', function(next) {
    // Check if document is new or a new password has been set
    if (this.isNew || this.isModified('password')) {
        // Saving reference to this because of changing scopes
        const document = this;
        bcrypt.hash(document.password, saltRounds,
            function(err, hashedPassword) {
                if (err) {
                    next(err);
                }
                else {
                    document.password = hashedPassword;
                    next();
                }
            });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

userschema.methods.isCorrectPassword = function(password, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function(err, same) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(err, same);
        }
    });
};

var User = mongoose.model('User',userschema);
module.exports = { User };
```

Register Route:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../models/user');
var router = express.Router();


router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("register route reached");
    console.log(req.body.username);
    const { email, username, password } = req.body;
    const user = new User.User({ email, username, password });
    user.save(function(err) {
        console.log("User save function reached");
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("error thing reached");
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            console.log("else statement reached");
            res.status(200).send("User succesfully registered");
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Did you try to print response body on server side?

Comment: I just did and it returns undefined

Comment: can you share the logs here? like which logs are getting printed and which are not

Comment: All of the logs are printed on server side, but nothing is being sent back to the browser

Comment: I think the issue might be client side but im not sure. I tried using axios instead of fetch and it still doesn't work